# What is the correct setting for max_client_conn using session pool mode in pgBouncer?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, pgbouncer

Without diving so much into web applications or database performance tuning etc, I wish to consult on one thing. pgBouncer has the following settings:

```
;; Total number of clients that can connect
max_client_conn = 5000

;; Default pool size.  20 is good number when transaction pooling
;; is in use, in session pooling it needs to be the number of
;; max clients you want to handle at any moment
default_pool_size = 500
```

Given that the web application I am running can only operate in `session` mode, is the configuration above correct assuming:

1. My web application does not go above the 5000 client connection mark
2. My PostgreSQL Database has a `max_connection` setting of 500

Or am I missing something here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get errors about too many open files long before you reach 5000 queued connections, and so need to change the limit using `ulimit -n` or by otherwise altering the kernel settings.  (Note that if your application needs max_client_conn to be that high, your application is almost certainly profoundly broken.  But that wasn't your question)

You don't want default_pool_size to be equal to max_connections. That would leave no connections left over for things like monitoring, reporting, or debugging, or anything else. So back off a few.  If 495 isn't enough, 500 probably wouldn't be enough either.

Note that 500 is unlikely to be a good setting of max_connections in the first place.  Do you have 500 CPUs, or a RAID with 500 spindles?  But again, that wasn't your question.

Comment: thank you again. It makes sense to set the `default_pool_size` to something lower than max_connections to leave room for other "clients". These past 2 days have been a roller coaster and I've got to say, I don't envy database administrators. Thanks again. After more research, I found my application needs just 1000 `max_client_conn` and a `default_pool_size` of 50. Things seem to be running well and we just did a mock quiz with 250 students. Seems i'm doing something right. Thanks again.